# Pass current_user and links together in fast_jsonapi, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastjsonapi

Rails version : 6.0.0
Ruby version : 2.6.3

## controller

```
render json: AreaSerializer.new(
      Area.all, paginate(pagy), params: { current_user: current_user }
    ), status: ok
```

## serializer

```
attributes :nodes do |area, params|
...
end
```

Error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)):
```

Comment: Add to question full serializer pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried another way and it was working,

**In Controller**

```rb
areas = Area.all

options = { 
            links: paginate(pagy), 
            params: { current_user: @current_user } 
          }

render json: AreaSerializer.new(areas, options),
       status: ok
```

**In serializer**

```
attributes :nodes do |area, params|
  area.users.where.not(id: params[:current_user].id)
end
```

And the links key is rendering automatically in Serializer.

---

#### Example output received by front-end:

```
{
  data: [
    {},
    {} // areas hash
  ],
  links: {
    first: "",
    last: "",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```rb
render json: AreaSerializer.new(
               Area.all, 
               { params: { paginate: paginate(pagy), current_user: @current_user } }
    ), status: ok
```

Serializer

```rb
attributes :nodes do |area, params|
  ...
  params[:current_user]
  params[:paginate]
  ...
end
```

Comment: So that do you think?

Comment: Here paginate(pagy) = {links: {first: " ", next: " ", last: " "}}, if i follow like u said, links are not rendering automatically.